# Finding an economic policy that worked in a developed country but failed in a developing one

Tags: development-economics

As the term paper of development economics in BSc, I am assigned this topic but I have no idea where to begin with. Of course I can’t look up every economic policy that was ever made then check whether it failed in a developing country but succeeded in a developed one. Can anyone suggest me a book or any article which might be of any use to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In his book [The Elusive Quest for Growth: Economists' Adventures and Misadventures in the Tropics](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/elusive-quest-growth), William Easterly discusses the failed efforts of states to use education, family planning, and debt forgiveness as means to grow out of poverty. You may find one policy that worked in developed countries.

Comment: Thank you! Ill surely look into it